# Which type of commands need to end with a semicolon(;)?

Tags: java

I am learning Java and can write a lot of programs but something that I haven't really understood is which type of commands need to end with a semicolon `;`.
I enter them mechanically but I want to learn where exactly they are needed.
For example, `import java.util.Scanner;` needs a semicolon `;` at the end but
`public static void main(String[] args)` doesn't, although it is actually where the program starts, right?

Comment: All declarations and all non-block statements needs to be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: You can always clarify the need for semicolon in any particular case by consulting the official language grammar https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html (this one is for java 8).

Comment: And for a more gentle start on the usage of semicolon in Java, consider reading through the topic Expressions, Statements, and Blocks at Oracle's Java tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html.

Answer (score 1):

Every command needs a semicolon (';') at the end so the program knows that this is the end of the command, sometimes you need to stretch a command over more than one line so the semicolon comes at the end of the last line of this command.

`public static void main(String[] args)` is a method. Methods conatin more commands and to differ what commands are in which method you surrond the commands with `{`and `}`. If you only worked with main so far you won't notice it as much but methods save you a lot of work. Instead of writing:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("One");
    System.out.println("Two");
    System.out.println("Three");
    System.out.println("One");
    System.out.println("Two");
    System.out.println("Three");
}
```

You can write another method and then call that, like this:

```
public static void prinNumbers()
{
    System.out.println("One");
    System.out.println("Two");
    System.out.println("Three");
}
```

This is a method that you now can call in main. Remember calling the method is a command and needs a semicolon.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    printNumbers();
    printNumbers();
}
```

I hope I could help you, you can find some more information about methods right [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon (;) needs to be used at the end of every statement different from a block declaration, e.g:

```
int variable;
System.out.println("Io");
```

`public static void main(String[] args)` is a method with a `body` (`{}`), fully declared as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

}
```

Which is a block.

The `String[] args` part is a declaration, but it's a parameter declaration, which doesn't need the semicolon (;) since its purpuse is to "finish" a statement, and in this case is a method (block).

Answer (score 0):

All the non-block statements must end with a semicolon -- `;`
Block statments are enclosed within curly braces -- `{}`
`import java.util.Scanner`; is a non-block statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 System.out.println("Hello World !");
}
```

is a block statement that contains one non-block statement.

Reading through the topic [Expressions, Statements, and Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)  at Oracle's Java tutorial will be helpful in understanding the use of semicolon `;` in a Java program.

Comment: [`if` statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) don't.

Comment: @AndyTurner Just `if` by itself, with or without a condition, is not really a full statement.

Comment: `{}` is a valid statement, and yet it doesn't have to be terminated.

Comment: @Someprogrammer well, no, `if` by itself is a keyword. But if statements are definitely statements.

Comment: @AndyTurner So for a full statement one would need e.g. something like `if (a) b;`, which is terminated with a semicolon. Or (for the person writing this answer) `if (a) { b; }` which isn't terminated (but the nested statement is).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I improved my answer...hope it is now complete.

Comment: Imports aren't statements, they are declarations. They're not executed.

Comment: @AndyTurner Let me quote, "To import a specific member into the current file, put an **import statement** at the beginning of the file before any type definitions but after the package statement" from Oracle's Java tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: @Sanjeev sadly, the Oracle tutorials often play fast and loose with terminology. The language spec defines that ["Every statement has a normal mode of execution in which certain computational steps are carried out."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1), that such lines are called [import declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5), and that  [the syntax of statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-19.html) does not include import declarations.

Comment: @AndyTurner Imports aren't declared; classes, variables, annotations are declared.

Comment: @AndyTurner I feel for a beginner like the OP, the mild terminology used in the Oracle Tutorial will be much more helpful than the rigorous terminology used in the Java Language Specification.